# Append query parameters after queryParam update in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, query-string

I defined the queryParams in the controller and I need to add additional query parameters which is not used in the Ember application and it can have any name. It's an analytics thing. Those query parameters are not known in advance thus, we are not able to define those analytics values in the queryParams property. What happens now is Ember deletes all additional parameter after the queryParams and URL binding is triggered.

Example:

In the Controller:

```
queryParams: ['fin', 'ftw'],
fin: null,
ftw: null,
```

url:

```
localhost:3000?fin=111&ftw=121&anatylicsvalue=1
```

when I change the value of fin or ftw, anatylicsvalue is removed. I need the app to retain that bit of string.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `analyticsvalue` within `queryParams` array of the controller, or `queryParams` json object of the router whether or not it is going to be used by the controller. So, if you declare `queryParams` as `['fin', 'ftw', 'analyticsvalue']` it will retain.

In order to achieve a somewhat dynamic query parameter (where even the name of the parameter is not known in advance), the only option I can suggest is using a named query parameter and using `JSON.stringify` to put the query parameters with that name. Take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/47c0f2499c4035e05b230c88fda2528a?openFiles=controllers.index.js%2C&route=%2F%3FadditionalParams%3D%257B%2522prop2%2522%253A0.4622525713200716%252C%2522prop3%2522%253A%25222017-06-26T17%253A48%253A22.768Z%2522%252C%2522prop0.6684603532438609%2522%253A%2522val0.2767980388833844%2522%257D). `index.js` route defines `queryParams` as `queryParams: ['fin', 'ftw', 'additionalParams']` and `additionalParams` query parameter holds dynamic parameters since it is a JSON object that can hold any dynamic sub-parameter. Take a look at the `updateAdditionalParams` inside `actions` it defines a dynamic property and dynamic values as you can see.

Unfortunately, Ember does not support custom query parameters that are not known in advance. You can use the approach I have illustrated in the twiddle. Hope this helps.

Comment: The additional queryParams could change so I need it to be dynamic. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @JazzGalano take a look at the answer I have updated regarding your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, Ember does not support custom query parameters that are not known in advance.

It's a shame there's no "remainder" capability, if I understand what you're saying correctly. If an SPA was called with the requirement that any query parameters that it does not understand must be passed through verbatim on all its outgoing URLs, the SPA would need to scrape these off itself during routing, outside the Ember mechanisms? Do I have this right?

With controllers going away, will all of the query parameter support end up on the route? Is there something we should be doing to "future-proof" our design now?